# Azure Function App Runtime not available in Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.4

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-2019, .net-6.0, azure-functions-runtime

I have an azure function app which is running in Visual Studio 2019. I updated the project to use the TargetFramework from .net 5.0 to .net 6.0 and I also have Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version 4.0.1 installed. Here is an image of the .csproj file

[image]

When I try to run the application I get the following error in a message box:

**"There is no Functions runtime available that matches the version specified in the project"**

What should I do to let it work ?

Comment: Try installing VS 2022, cause 2019 does not support .NET 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the issue you're facing when migrating from .Net 5 to .Net 6 in Visual Studio 2019:**
[image]

**In Visual Studio 2019,**
[image]

In **Visual Studio 2022**, these are the additional options of Functions Runtimes available:
[image]

And Migrating from .Net 5 Isolated to .Net 6 only in any editor will not work as you can see in below screenshot: there will be some worker extensions packages will be missed from the .Net 6 Azure Functions comparing to .Net 5.

[image]

After adding the Worker extensions, migrating the required packages from .Net 5 Iso to .Net 6 will gives the target assembly version error and also the above error like `No function runtime specified`, etc.

When Migrating from .Net 5 Isolated to .Net Isolated in VS 2022, it will run successfully as you can see in below screenshot:

[image]

According to this [MSFT Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide), Out-of-process Isolated environments are .Net 5.0 and .Net 6.0.

Isolated (out-of-process) .Net Project has some set of unique packages, which implement both core functionality and binding extensions.

Therefore, try migration of .Net 5 Isolated to .Net 6 Isolated as shown above, runs successfully.

Answer (score 3):

To use .NET6 you will need to update to VS2022 in order to utilize the correct frameworks.